# Pulsate not executed after click with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a pulsate:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".pane > a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().effect("pulsate", { times:2 }).fadeOut('slow');
      });

  });
  </script>
```

Then the PHP:

```
<?php

        if($_SESSION['username']) {
            if(isset ($_GET['id'])) {    
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM reviews WHERE id='". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ."'");                       
            }
        }

        $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews");   
        if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {  
            echo ("<div class=''><strong>Sorry!</strong> No reviews have been created!</div>"); 
        }   
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){
        ?>

    <div class="pane">
    <a href="reviews/editReview/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><img src="http://uploadir.com/u/6hmr4fr1" alt="delete" class="delete" /></a>
    <?php echo $row['comment'] ?>
    </div>
```

It works but doesn't delete from the database. I'm working on an AJAX script, which works perfect, but it's something I'm not doing right here.

It pulsates out with:

`<a href="reviews/editReview/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"`rel="noAJAX"`>`

but when I take out the `rel="noAJAX"` it deletes the information from the database, which I want to happen, but it isn't pulsating then deleting.

Any ideas? I'm using `jQuery UI 1.8.2` & `jQuery 1.5`

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is stopping the deleting from happening, and replacing the action with pulsating. If you want both to happen, you'll need to make an AJAX request to delete the data.